# how to set superset SQLALCHEMY URI to connect HiveServer2 with custom auth

Tags: hive, apache-superset

Superset want to connect HiveServer2 datasource with custom auth (that is specify username and password), python code as below is ok

```
from pyhive import hive

host_name = "192.168.0.38"
port = 10000
user = "admin"
password = "password"
database="test_db"

def hiveconnection(host_name, port, user,password, database):
    conn = hive.Connection(host=host_name, port=port, username=user, password=password,
                           database=database, auth='CUSTOM')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('select item_sk,reason_sk, account_credit from returns limit 5')
    result = cur.fetchall()

    return result
```

but how to set Superset `SQLALCHEMY URI` ?

```
hive://hive@{hostname}:{port}/{database}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see:
https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/18699#discussioncomment-2170334

```
hive://username:password@hostname:port/database?auth=CUSTOM
```